# Home network SNAFU

Tags: router, home-networking, nas, switch

Our home was recently completed in a cookie cutter subdivision. I had them drop four Cat 6 cables throughout the house. One to the living room, master bedroom, office and office closet. I wanted the modem, router and NAS to sit in the office closet. BUT, because I didn't spell it out for them that I would like all the cat 6 lines to meet in the office closet they ran them down to the downstairs coat closet with all the phone lines, coaxial and security system meet.

Here's what I am thinking and please let me know if it's possible. 
I can fish a close coaxial line to the office closet. Drop that into the closet, plug cable modem into the new coaxial line, cable modem into router, router into gigabit switch ( run NAS off of switch and smart home hubs off of router) then into cat 6 drop/outlet.
From there I will install a second switch in the coat closet down stairs linking the rest of the drops in the house,

Will this work????

Comment: This should work, but why not just move the modem & router downstairs to the closet and save yourself having to run a new coax line and buy a new switch?

Comment: If I was him, I would want the modem & Router in my office for all my devices and for quick troubleshooting when working from home.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should. 
Having a second switch or router in your coat closet would not be a problem. You won't have any DHCP issues or degradation in speed.

Depending on how long the coaxial line is, you might have to ask your ISP to send someone out to boost your signal db.

You could also get a wifi to ethernet switch, or use Wi-Fi Range Extender (one with Ethernet hubs) and set it up to be a wireless link to your wifi router not as an extender.

Don't forget there are also Ethernet over power, and Ethernet over cable options.